# Why does Apache on Ubuntu show blank for unknown file extension ... even with DefaultType text/plain?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have installed Apache in a VM environment for both CentOS and Ubuntu.  In both environments, the Apache configuration variable `DefaultType` is set to `text/plain`.

If I have a file with an unknown extension - say, `dummy.xxx`, containing just a few random characters, located in the document root folder, and I type `localhost/dummy.xxx` into firefox, then on CentOS, the random characters appear in the browser output.  However, on Ubuntu, they do not - an empty page appears (even when you 'view source').  (Note that regular .htm files *do* appear properly on Ubuntu.)

This issue may be relevant to an unrelated problem I'm having that I am not discussing here (for simplicity, and to save time) - so this question is not just for interest's sake.

I know this is a short question - if *any* other details are necessary, such as the version of the various software components, please do ask and I'll dig that information up.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I have seen this sort of criticism directed at other questions that are not specific to a single programming environment, but involve detailed programmer's knowledge, and I have agreed with those who feel such questions belong on this forum.  For example, in this case I make reference to httpd.conf with its declarative scripting style: `DefaultType text/plain`.  However, if you feel that despite such constructs, this is not an issue involving sufficiently clear-cut programming, and therefore does not belong on this forum. please feel free to say so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the actual headers coming back from the server to see if they include a Content-Type: header?   If you do have a Content-Type: header, and it is set to text/plain, then your problem is client-side, not server side.

Also, double-check your mime.types file.  Any matching entry in mime.types will override the apache.conf's DefaultType setting.